# Fragment error when getting string from Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I m launch an activity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    Hosting.class
            );
            intent.putExtra("host", item.getTitle());
            startActivity(intent);
```

Now i have 5 fragment on this activity with tabs, on fragment 5 i need get the host string with:

host = getArguments().getString("host");

(In normal activity i get this string with `getIntent().getStringExtra("host")` but in fragment didn't work...)

but app crash with:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Why this? This is my first android application..

Comment: the arguments inside the fragments are not the same as the bundle within the activity. If you insert your fragments programmatically, you can pass a bundle to each fragment. If on the other hand you insert them via xml, you will have to obtain them via the fragment manager and then use setters to pass your data

Comment: Dynamic string in xml not good idea i think, how to work with bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its likely you are not setting the `host` string extra in your fragment's arguments on creation. You can either do that or in your fragment code just keep on using `getIntent().getStringExtra("host")` by first calling `getActivity()`:

```
host = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("host")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with fragments and want to interact between the fragment and activity , i.e , parse data back and forth , check for clicks etc , it is usually advisable to make an interface and implement that in the activity .

For reference you can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyykjIPNBXY)
, it is very helpful